# why does the index increases before looping

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I cannot figure out why the for loop counter increases before I want it too / before it executes the entire for-loop block. I have littered the code with print statements for debugging, here is the code:

```
public void findSubSeq() {
    temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    temp.add(vals.get(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < (vals.size()-2); i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " index in array, for");
        if (vals.get(i) < vals.get(i++)) {
            System.out.println(i + " index in array, if 1");
            temp.add(vals.get(i++));
            System.out.println(i + " index in array, if 2");
            System.out.println(this.getlargest());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(i + " index in array, else 1");
            compareALs();
            System.out.println(i + " index in array, else 2");
            temp.add(vals.get(i++));
            System.out.println(i + " index in array, else 3");
            System.out.println(this.getlargest());
        }
    }
}
```

In the run of the code we can see that the counter i increases before the end of the for-loop. I am really confused. I have also tried a for-each loop with similar results. 
Here is the run:
before subarrayB creation

before fillAL

Input file: inp

[1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5]

before findSubSeq

0 index in array, for

1 index in array, else 1

1 index in array, else 2

2 index in array, else 3

[1]

3 index in array, for

4 index in array, else 1

4 index in array, else 2

5 index in array, else 3

[1]

Comment: Why downvote? He obviously tried to understand where the error comes from...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really need to avoid using i++ inside the loop.  That is what is causing your index variable to get incremented when you don't expect it.  For example, your code does this:

```
if (vals.get(i) < vals.get(i++))
```

I think you really want to do this:

```
if (vals.get(i) < vals.get(i+1))
```

Similarly, when you add to temp, you really don't want to do i++, you want:

```
temp.add(vals.get(i+1));
```

Answer (score 5):

You have `vals.get(i++)` which increments `i`. When used this way, `++` is a postincrement operator.

Comment: As a side note : _i++_ will use the value of i, then increment it. If you use _++i_ , the value will first be incremented, then evaluated.

Comment: which is one of the really baaaad things you should never ever do.

Comment: @Hannes Is it really bad? Why?

Comment: @Fabinout I was referring to the method to increase the for loop counter within a loop. One shall never modify the for counter.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (vals.get(i) < vals.get(i++))
```

statement is like `x < x`, because increment accrues after `get` calling.

Use

```
if (vals.get(i) < vals.get(++i))
```

If you want to compare i-th and i+1 th elements.

The second: you have 3 increments of `i` in one cycle in one case by `i`. One in `for` cycle, the second in `if` and the 3-d, in `add`. Is it that which you planned?